# Expired/removed job appearing in sidebar

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I was navigating today through the site, when a job offer caught my attention:
[image: job offer]

However, clicking on the jod lead me to the following page:
[image: job offer]

I think this is a bug, expired job offers should not be listed.